# Fetch Callfire form values using Callfire REST api

Tags: rest, callfire

I have went through https://developers.callfire.com/docs.htm and cannot find any endpoint or webhook which retrieves the form values entered by the agent while on call. Kindly assist.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are working on IVR scenarios? If this is the case, then you are looking for Advanced section of IVRs, allowing you to make HTTP requests to your service with input gathered during the call: https://www.callfire.com/help/docs/advanced-tab-buttons#section2